# Determine if the described set is a subspace. If so give a proof. If not explain why not. a and b are real numbers and integers.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the described set is a subspace. If so give a proof. If not explain why not. $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

The subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of the vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}$, where a and b are integers?

Comment: That's not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Do you mean vectors $(a,b,c)$ where $a,b,c$ are integers?

Comment: The integer constrant should make you suspicious if you can multiply with aritrary scalars

Comment: its R^2 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, your set is a subspace if the following hold:

1. $c*\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix} \in V$.
2. $\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} \in V$
3. For any $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}c\\ d\end{bmatrix} \in V$, then $\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}c\\ d\end{bmatrix} \in V$.

If you can show these, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

A subspace is closed under scalar multiplication. If you have a non-zero integer vector and you multiply by an irrational number, can you get an integer vector?

Comment: no you cannot. That makes sense, but how would I write out the proof?